# Azure Datalake Arm Template Key Vault Key Version

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

Similar to referencing the ResourceId of the Key Vault-

```
"keyVaultResourceId": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', parameters('keyVaultName'))]",
```

Is it possible to reference, in the same resource group, a previously created key vault key version into an ARM template that is deploying a User Managed encrypted Datalake?

I'm trying something like this below:

```
"keyVaultResourceId": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', parameters('keyVaultName'))]",

"encryptionKeyName": "[parameters('encryptionKeyName')]",

"encryptionKeyVersion": "[list(resourceGroup(), '/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', parameters('keyVaultName'), parameters('encryptionKeyName')), '2016-10-01').encryptionKeyVersion ]"
```

What is the correct json syntax supposed to look like?

Comment: i would be really surprised if something like this worked in arm template. keyvault and arm templates don't go really well together in terms of exposed capabilities

Comment: The ARM template published on Azure Samples assumes the user knows the name and version of the Key Vault encryption key. I'm not sure whether you can ask for the latest version string through an ARM template.